Blender UV map is very small resolution using TexTool addon
This is my UV map now:

my goal is to make it like this, but when the map are enlarged, parts climb out of the mesh fields of the map.

Tell me how to implement it correctly. I'm learning so if you need clarification let me know
(My addon dont resize checker map)

is it a problem if the mesh is bigger than the grid? You can still repeat the image in the UV Editor, you can also use a Mapping node in order to change the texture size

The islands you see and manipulate in the UV Editor are not the texture, they're the way programs will convert the vertices from 3D space to a 2D texture.

So when you scale them up or move them around you aren't changing the texture resolution, only the ratio of texture resolution -> real-world space (texel density).
TexTools does allow you to resize the checker map though. Right here.


do I understand correctly? islands have no effect on the texture and we can scale uv maps beyond the island?
and to change the size of the checker, do you need to press the resize button in the addon? if so then resizing the checker doesn't work for me, could it be due to having to remove all modifiers

Yes, UV islands scale is completely unrelated to the texture itself. The 0-1 UV space you see repeats infinitely in all directions. Scaling the islands up or down only changes how many pixels of the texture will fit on each face. I would try resize, then click the checker map button. If that doesn't work see if the material is being assigned correctly. That's where it would be visible.
